# Arduino - "expected primary-expression before '.' token" Error

Tags: error

```
#include "Ultrasonic.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

// Set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  lcd.begin();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
Ultrasonic ultrasonic(11, 12); //Ultrasonic ultrasonic(Trig,Echo);
void loop()
{
  int a = (Ultrasonic.Ranging(CM));
  if (a >= 15 && a < 20)
  { Serial.println("guvenli");
    lcd.print("guvenli");
    delay(500);
    lcd.clear();
    tone(3, 2000, 100);
    delay(500);
    noTone(3);
  }
  if (a >= 10 && a < 15) {
    Serial.println("guvenli dikkat");
    lcd.print("guvenli dikkat");
    delay(500);
    lcd.clear();
    tone(3, 2000, 50);
    delay(250);
    noTone(3);
  }
  if (a < 5)
  {
    Serial.println("vurdun");
    lcd.print("vurdun");
    delay(500);
    lcd.clear();**uıhhf
    tone(3, 2000, 50);
    delay(50);
    noTone(3);
  }
}
```

In this code i'm getting an error like this:

```
   C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_modified_sketch_113625\sketch_apr29a.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketch_apr29a:19:22: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

   int a = (Ultrasonic.Ranging(CM)); 

                      ^

exit status 1
expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

Comment: Please show as a full working example of your code, that shows the problem. This cannot be your full code. Also please provide a link to the library, that you use for Ultrasonic.

Comment: http://pasted.co/172df900

Comment: I guess you used the following libraries: [LiquidCrystal-I2C](https://github.com/fdebrabander/Arduino-LiquidCrystal-I2C-library) and [Ultrasonic-HC-SR04](https://github.com/JRodrigoTech/Ultrasonic-HC-SR04)

Comment: And please copy your full code into the question, so that it does not rely on a link, that may become invalid over time. I did that for you now.

Comment: If I remove the `**uıhhf` in line 40 (which does seem like a typo), your sketch compiles fine for me. I don't receive the shown error. I'm using Arduino IDE 1.8.5 and Arduino Uno as target board.

Comment: this is all of code

Comment: now im getting this code: "Arduino:1.8.8 (Windows 8.1), Kart:"Arduino/Genuino Uno"

C:\Users\ETKullanici\Desktop\sketch_apr29a\sketch_apr29a.ino: In function 'void loop()':

sketch_apr29a:16:21: error: 'class Ultrasonic' has no member named 'Ranging'

   int a=(ultrasonic.Ranging(CM)); 

                     ^

exit status 1
'class Ultrasonic' has no member named 'Ranging'

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences."

Comment: Then maybe you have a different ultrasonic library, than I linked above. Please provide a link to the library, that you really use.

Comment: i think it's not about library issue, you have `error: expected primary-expression before '.' token

   int a = (Ultrasonic.Ranging(CM));` but you are using a variable `Ultrasonic ultrasonic(11, 12);` Please check your code again!!.

Comment: @chrisl: You replaced the original code that generated the “expected primary-expression” error with modified code that no longer has that error. Why did you do that? Now the question makes no sense anymore.

Comment: @AnT I just copied the code from the pasted link, that the OP provided. You may vote to revoke my edit of the question

Comment: @chrisl: I understand. It means that the edit was made by the author of the code. Yet, it does not change the fact that the code no longer matches the error message, defeating the purpose of this entire question.

Answer (score 2):

`Ultrasonic` is a class name. Why are you trying to use it before a `.` in an expression?

Judging by the declaration, you need `ultrasonic`. That is your object name. `ultrasonic`, not `Ultrasonic`.

Comment: Comparing the provided code with the error text, I would bet that one or the other is a typo, notice the case of 'ultrasonic' in the code does not match the corresponding line in the error.

Comment: @Kelly S. French: Well, if you look through the editing history, you'll see that the code in the original post did match the error text. Meanwhile, the pastebin version linked by the author in the comments is slightly different - the `Ultrasonic` error is already fixed. Later the code here was replaced with pastebin version. So the question became inconsistent with itself.

Comment: Good point, I had not considered looking through the edit history. My misgivings were more around my surprise at the error text given that a problem with strict case-matching wouldn't typically be related to a missing 'primary expression' as usually there needs to be a named identifier before the '.' and to expect an expression there would make me wonder if the cause were elsewhere, for instance the snippet ' **uıhhf in line 40 ' mentioned by chrisl, which definitely look like a syntax error but I can't see how it would generate that error either. Did the OP not include the whole error log?